# Setting microseconds to two decimal places in axis format in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

I'm building a simple programm which will show a graph of athlet's progress. So we have two sets of data: age and a result at that age.

This is my code:

```
x = [15, 16, 17]  # age of athlete
y_raw = ['52,70', '52,55', '53,03']  # time in string
y = []
for item in y_raw:
    item_datatime = datetime.strptime(item, '%S,%f')  # transform time in string into datetime format
    y.append(item_datatime)

plt.style.use('seaborn')
plt.plot(x, y, 'bo', label='Athlete')
ax_time_format = '%S,%f'
plt.xticks(range(min(x) - 1, max(x) + 2))
plt.tight_layout()
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_locator(mpl_dates.AutoDateLocator())
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(mpl_dates.DateFormatter(ax_time_format))

plt.show()
```

And the result:
[image]

I want y-axis to be precise on two decimal places so it should go from bootom up 52,60 then 52,70 then 52,80 and so on. I have no idea how to tackle this one (i tried writing  `ax_time_format = '%S,%f'` as `ax_time_format = '%S,%02f'` but that isn't working.

So, any ideas here?

p.s. I know how to do this in normal number format, but that approach isn't working on datatime format (or I just do it wrong).

Comment: you could either directly use `strftime()` to create your custom y tick labels and modify the string, or get the labels after creation and modify them. But as you I think there should be a better way using the format string.

Comment: probably hackish, but you could multiply the actual values with 100 (or what ever precision/unit you need) and display the seconds. But this is not very elegant, especially not if you want to continue to work with that data.

Comment: @sarbot: Thanks for your suggestions. If there isn't a more elegant solution, I'll definately try your "hacky" one. Cheers!